# I need 10 integer of array and display the sum and here is my code I dont know where the error is

Tags: arrays, sum, mips

Write a MIPS program that defines a one-dimensional array of 10 integers in the static area of the data segment, asks the user to input all 10 array elements, computes, and displays their sum.

```
.data
arr: .word 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
msg: .asciiz "Result: "
.text
.globl main

main:
addi $t0, $zero, 0 # clear i
addi $t1, $zero, 0 # clear sum
ori $t2, $zero, 10 # Initializing t2 to its constant value 10
la $t3, arr # load address of array into t4
loop:
slt $t4, $t0, $t2 # compare, $t4 = i < sum ? 1 : 0
beq $t4, $zero, end # if i is not < 10, exit the loop
lw $t4, 0($t3) # load current array element into t4
add $t1, $t1, $t4 # add it to sum
add $t0, $t0, 1 # increment i
add $t3, $t3, 4 # increment current array element pointer
j loop
end:
addi $v0, $zero, 4 # Now we print out result: string
la $a0, msg
syscall
addi $v0, $zero, 1 # followed by the actual sum (which is in t1)
add $a0, $t1, $zero
syscall
jr $ra
.end main
```

Comment: What is it doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using MARS or QtSpim?

Comment: I'm using MARS there something wrong in the code the sum of 10 integers are not displaying

Comment: What you're saying is not specific enough.  Try to relate the complete actual error condition.

Comment: thankyou for the kindness to help me but I already solved it last night

Comment: the time that I removed the "jr $ra " the program run with no error and the sum also display

Comment: Yes, you're using MARS and MARS does not "call" `main`, so you cannot "return" from `main`.  You could use the syscall #10 to properly terminate the program.